# Unknown OAuthException from basic OpenGraph user API calls

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

Starting around Friday night, and continuing as of this morning, we have been seeing errors for simple open graph queries for valid users.

For example: https://graph.facebook.com/833150354

Returns:

```
  {
      "error": {
          "type": "OAuthException",
          "message": "An unknown error has occurred."
      }
  }
```

But, the user is valid:
http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=833150354

It looks like at least one other person has run into this: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=20490

Has anyone else seen this behavior and, if so, found a work around?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometime between 7:50 and 8:50 PM EST on 9/13, this problem went away for us.  All the other cases I've seen shared also appear to work now.

Love that Facebook never acknowledged the issue in any way I could find even though it was broken for 5 days.

Answer (score 1):

Experienced the same error with 2 of our app's users today. Their OG representation throws the error, but their regular FB profile works fine. Sounds like an OpenGraph bug, not sure of any possible workaround :\

Answer (score 0):

I get the "unknown error" all the time, when I query the graph using the application's token.  When I have the current user's token, that works.  But the application token fails.

(The app's token worked before the oauth upgrade, BTW.)

Comment: The case I'm seeing is more basic.  No tokens required.  Someone else has now reported the issue as well: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=20534